# Vue child component not updating dynamically

Tags: vue.js, dhtmlx

I am at my wits end trying to change a child component.

I am using a dhtmlx gantt chart, as per image attached (2nd). I am trying to hide the left grid (dynamically) that has the Taskname etc in it as especially on an iPad it takes up a lot of real estate.

I want to change it dynamically. I have deducted that it can be done by setting the width of the grid to zero.

```
gantt.config.grid_width = this.showGrid;
```

If I set showGrid to 0 then it does not show the grid. (1st image)

In the parent this is gridWidth.

```
 <gantt
    v-if="showGant"
      :key="componentKey"
      class="left-container"
      :tasks="tasks"
      :showGrid="gridWidth"
      @task-updated="logTaskUpdate"
      @link-updated="logLinkUpdate"
      @task-selected="selectTask"
    ></gantt>
```

But I want it to be able to be done dynamically as it is needed at times to edit and add tasks.

child component - the dhtmlx gantt chart

```
loadGantt() {
      gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d";
      gantt.config.highlight_critical_path = true;
      gantt.config.grid_width = this.showGrid;
      gantt.attachEvent("onTaskSelected", (id) => {
        let task = gantt.getTask(id);
        this.$emit("task-selected", task);
      });
      gantt.attachEvent("onTaskIdChange", (id, new_id) => {
        if (gantt.getSelectedId() == new_id) {
          let task = gantt.getTask(new_id);
          this.$emit("task-selected", task);
        }
      });
      gantt.config.grid_width = this.showGrid;
      gantt.init(this.$refs.gantt);
      gantt.createDataProcessor((entity, action, data, id) => {
        this.$emit(`${entity}-updated`, id, action, data);
      });
      gantt.parse(this.$props.tasks);
      console.log(this.showGrid)
    }
```

[image: without grid]
I have tried to reload the component using a v-if as well as a :key but neither works.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. BTW, the props are getting passed but the chart does not update dynamically, only when the data component gridWidth is hard coded.

[image: with grid]

Comment: I hadn't heard of DHTMLX until your question, and then found their website.  Hopefully someone will answer here on SO, but have you tried contacting the company with you question?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a custom layout configuration, you can toggle the `gantt.config.show_grid` property and use the `gantt.render()` method to repaint the chart:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_show_grid_config.html

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_render.html

Otherwise, you need to change the layout configuration and reinitialize Gantt to see the changes:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__layout_config.html

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_init.html

Here are examples:

Toggle grid:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/763029f57

toggle grid + layout:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5fc27c820

Here is a Vue demo:

https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/f23270e75a32303a0dbea5efc27e7544/vue+toogle-grid.zip